# Extract value of array and add in the same select mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to the mongoDB aggregation and I have this situation. I have this Json and I need to convert by "select" this object:

```
{
    "type": "PF",
    "code": 12345
    "Name": Darth Vader,
    "currency": "BRL",
    "status": "SINGLE",
    "adress": [
        {
            "localization": "DEATH STAR",
            "createDate": 1627990848665
        },
        {
            "localization": "TATOOINE",
            "createDate": 1627990555665
        },
    ]
}
```

this way:

```
{
    "type": "PF",
    "code": 12345
    "Name": Darth Vader,
    "currency": "BRL",
    "status": "SINGLE",
    "localization": "DEATH STAR",
    "createDate": 1627990848665
},
{
    "type": "PF",
    "code": 12345
    "Name": Darth Vader,
    "currency": "BRL",
    "status": "SINGLE",
    "localization": "TATOOINE",
    "createDate": 1627990555665
}
```

So, after my query is complete, I will have 02 objects instead of 01. How can I do this?
I would like to do this via select because after converting I will sort by createDate and limit the number of records to return to the API. I'm using Criteria em my project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Unfortunately no because I need to repeat the same informations of the first element to others. =(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is `$unwind`, this will make 1 copy of the document, for each member of the array.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NP714tlni23)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$user.adress"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "user": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$user",
          "$user.adress"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "user.adress"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "createDate": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

---

Edit1 (the above is if `user` is a field, if it was the name of the collection)

- `$$ROOT` is a system variable that has as value all the document

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y3ylj9Zg75l)

Query

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$adress"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$$ROOT",
          "$adress"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "adress"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "createDate": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

Comment: I have just a only question. I'm looking in my json and I made a mistake... I dont have the name USER. How can I do in this situation? Only this way...
{
    "type": "PF",
    "code": 12345
    "Name": Darth Vader,
    "currency": "BRL",
    "status": "SINGLE",
    "adress": [
        {
            "localization": "DEATH STAR",
            "createDate": 1627990848665
        },
        {
            "localization": "TATOOINE",
            "createDate": 1627990555665
        },
    ]
}

Comment: i was wondering a bit, if user was a field or the name of the collection, try the edit, i think you will be fine.

Comment: Yes... That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much (AGAIN)!! =)

Comment: I remember about another situation... I have the actual location in the Json and I need  to keep the actual location and reply the other informations for the "children" as you show me. How I keep the actual location in this case and add the "children" for the return..????

https://mongoplayground.net/p/W4hBM0KN1UD

https://mongoplayground.net/p/W4hBM0KN1UD

Comment: i am confused a bit, if its different question maybe ask new one, with new data and the expected output you want. so people can help.

Comment: I undestend... so... I create a new questuions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117709/reply-head-informations-and-add-extract-array-to-same-result
If you have time and could please help me again... I'll be very thankful

Comment: Takis, this situation caused this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209289/mongodb-unset-if-condition-is-met ....could you help me?

Comment: Hi Takis... =)
Could you please help me again?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916346/mongodb-updatemany

Comment: how you doing? =) Could you please help me again?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74944874/mongodb-get-last-transaction-per-ucode