# MongoDB $unset If condition is met

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, aggregation-framework, unset

Someone colud please help me with this situation?

I have this fake JSON...

```
[
  {
    "user": {
      "type": "PF",
      "code": 12345,
      "Name": "Darth Vader",
      "currency": "BRL",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "localization": "NABOO",
      "createDate": 1627990848665,
      "olderAdress": [
        {
          "localization": "DEATH STAR",
          "status": "BLOCKED",
          "createDate": 1627990848665
        },
        {
          "localization": "TATOOINE",
          "status": "CANCELLED",
          "createDate": 1627990555665
        },
        {
          "localization": "ALDERAAN",
          "status": "INACTIVED",
          "createDate": 1627990555665
        },
        
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to remove the field `code` if the status equals "BLOCKED" or "CANCELLED". I'm using aggregate because I'm doing a lot of things before [Practical Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QehOjXOEpbz). How can I do that??

I need this result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user": {
      "Name": "Darth Vader",
      "createDate": 1.627990848665e+12,
      "currency": "BRL",
      "localization": "DEATH STAR",
      "status": "BLOCKED",
      "type": "PF"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user": {
      "Name": "Darth Vader",
      "createDate": 1.627990555665e+12,
      "currency": "BRL",
      "localization": "TATOOINE",
      "status": "CANCELLED",
      "type": "PF"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user": {
      "Name": "Darth Vader",
      "code": 12345,
      "createDate": 1.627990555665e+12,
      "currency": "BRL",
      "localization": "ALDERAAN",
      "status": "INACTIVED",
      "type": "PF"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "user": {
      "Name": "Darth Vader",
      "code": 12345,
      "createDate": ISODate("2021-09-16T17:36:26.405Z"),
      "currency": "BRL",
      "localization": "NABOO",
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "type": "PF"
    }
  }
]
```

Soo...Independent of the name, I will check  the status and if you contemplate the condition I will remove the field `code`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query

- uses a system variable `$$REMOVE` if a field gets this value its removed
- so the condition is `user.code` , keep old value if not `"BLOCKED"`,`"CANCELLED"` , else `"$$REMOVE"` the field

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7ZBicsmpuMC)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "user.code": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$in": [
              "$user.status",
              [
                "BLOCKED",
                "CANCELLED"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "$$REMOVE",
          "$user.code"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

**Edit**

The above code checks the `user.status` but you want remove code or not based onthe `user.olderAdress.status` (after the unwind)
(its 2 fields with same name status)

Query (add this after the stages you already have)

[Test code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_oxQFp5mQ34)

```js
{
    "$set": {
      "user.code": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$in": [
              "$user.status",
              [
                "BLOCKED",
                "CANCELLED"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "$$REMOVE",
          "$user.code"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Partially is OK... the problem is... as I wrote before, I have others piperlines (https://mongoplayground.net/p/QehOjXOEpbz) I not sure in what moment I introduce this $set...

Comment: looks like you can add it first combined with the `$addfields` you already have, set=addfields, see [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJy_a9x-bKr)

Comment: But if you run this example as you sent me... You can see the "code" was removed of every register... not only of the conditional...

Comment: yes but this isnt expected? "Name": "Darth Vader" was status : "BLOCKED" , so in all his addreses it will not have the code field.  see [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SQBOXH-ZMIk) the user Darth Vader2 still have its code because had status "ACTIVE"

Comment: No..  If you run this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QehOjXOEpbz) you will see 04 registers. My idea is if this register has the status blocked or cancelled, then the field `code` will be removed else, the field `code` stay present in the document.

Comment: but this is what is happening see again [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SQBOXH-ZMIk) "Darth Vader2" keeps the code field because active,  but "Darth Vader" doesnt have the field code because "BLOCKED" , if still doesnt work, update the question if you can with example output data, add for example 2 examples blocked or active(like the code from the link)

Comment: ok... I updated the question and put more details!

Comment: it had 2 fields named status, and i ddint see the nested one, now ok , you wanted to change the data after the unwind, based on the nested status not the top level status,
I think this time will be ok.

Comment: Takis... PERFECT!!! 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Takis how are you?... can you help me again???  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384943/mongodb-add-field-in-array-only-is-the-arry-is-not-null