# MongoDB UpdateMany

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to update various fields in mongo creating a new field. Example:

```
db.paymentTransaction.updateOne(
    {status: "PARTIALLY_REFUNDED"},
    {amount: EXISTS} 
    {
        $set: {
            "amountRefundRemaining": {
                FIELD_B  - FIELD_A
            }
        }
    }
)
```

I need to create the field amountRefundRemaining. But I need to fill this new field with the result of the substraction of Field_B minus Field_A. But I only need to do this where status=PARTIALLY_REFUNDED and amount exists

Im using mongoDB 4.4.
Any ideias?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you need in more details?

Comment: Sure... I need to create the field amountRefundRemaining. But I need to fill this new field with the result of the substraction of Field_B minus Field_A. But I only need to do this where status=PARTIALLY_REFUNDED and amount exists.

Comment: You should add this comment in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- if `status=PARTIALLY_REFUNDED` and `amount exists`
- add field `amountRefundRemaining` with value `FIELD_B  - FIELD_A`

*pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6233cd40f7e3c64c6511e142)

```js
update(
{"$and": 
 [{"status": {"$eq": "PARTIALLY_REFUNDED"}}, {"amount": {"$exists": true}}]},
[{"$set": 
   {"amountRefundRemaining": {"$subtract": ["$FIELD_B", "$FIELD_A"]}}}],
{"multi": true})
```

Comment: OK but I need to this for the all documents...

https://mongoplayground.net/p/BJ_evTVSKFg

how can I do?

Comment: i updated the answer, you had updateone on question so i was confused a bit, see your driver for updateMany also how to call depends on your driver

Comment: Perfect... Takis... with the {"multi": true} does work like a glove. Thks a lot!

Comment: Takis, can you help me again?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69933707/mongodb-extract-document

Comment: Takis... how are you? Could you please help me again?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880683/filter-mongodb-aggreagtion