# MongoDB Aggregation filter on documents within documents

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, projection

Can you help me with a situation...
I Have this json but I would like to return only the nodes.

```
{
   "_id":{
      "userArea":NumberInt(4927)
   },
   "pages":{
      "12":{
         "page":NumberInt(2635), 
         "progress":"COMPLETED",
         "progressType":"USER_PROGRESS",
         "end":11
      },
      "13":{
         "page":NumberInt(2627),
         "progress":"COMPLETED",
         "progressType":"USER_PROGRESS",
         "end":ISODate("2018-04-19T15:04:29.000+0000")
      }
      "14":{
         "page":NumberInt(2627),
         "progress":"CANCELLED",
         "progressType":"USER_PROGRESS",
         "end":ISODate("2018-04-19T15:04:29.000+0000")
      }
   }
}
```

This way.... without header

```
      "12":{
         "page":NumberInt(2635), 
         "progress":"COMPLETED",
         "progressType":"USER_PROGRESS",
         "end":11
      },
      "13":{
         "page":NumberInt(2627),
         "progress":"COMPLETED",
         "progressType":"USER_PROGRESS",
         "end":ISODate("2018-04-19T15:04:29.000+0000")
      }
```

Can you help me? I need to filter only the completed!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First use `$objectToArray` to generate an array and can filter the values using the value `v`. This is done into the `input`.
- Then with that input values you can filter the elements whose `progress` value is not `CANCELLED`. And convert again to an object with `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "pages": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$pages"
            },
            "cond": {
              "$ne": [
                "$$this.v.progress",
                "CANCELLED"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rRRkvFJxwQ3)

Sorry, on my first attemp I read "without header" and I thought you wanted using `$replaceRoot` but I think this new query is what you want (also avoiding `$unwind`).

But I think you say "without hedaer" to show the output simplified in the question. Also if you can't output the header simply add a new stage using `$replaceRoot`. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/35M1i30n1rh)

Comment: But who can I remove de node Cancelled?

Comment: I missunderstood the question, I've edited.

Comment: Perfect J.F. The second one is perfect to me! Thnks so much my friend!!!

Comment: Nice one. Thanks

Comment: General design note:   In general, it is a poor idea to make values into keys e.g. `"12": { "page"...`  The `$objectToArray` trick turns keys (LVAL) into values (RVAL) but unless you absolutely *have* to, best to model your data as a real array, e.g. `"pages":[
      {
         "pageID":"12",
         "page":NumberInt(2635), 
         "progress":"COMPLETED",
         "progressType":"USER_PROGRESS",
         "end":11
      },
      {
         "pageID":"13",
         "page":NumberInt(2627),
         "progress":"COMPLETED",
...
      ]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do many pipelines as in [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C4N4EaAIM5j)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "p": {
        "$objectToArray": "$pages"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$p"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "p.v.progress": "COMPLETED"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "p": {
        "$addToSet": "$p"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "a": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$p"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$a"
    }
  }
])
```

1. Reshape so that you can apply filter.
2. Group again to get back to your original schema. Else, you can stop at $match pipeline.

If possible, change your schema, Do not use dynamic keys.

Comment: Perfect Gibbs... Thanks!!!

Comment: Other answer is significantly smaller and does not incur `$unwind` and `$group` costs.

Comment: Yes, your action was right.