# MongoDB get last transaction per UCODE

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I need to filter the records below but I need to return only the last transaction (the most recent transaction) by UCODE.

```
_id                        ucode                         value           createDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
63a997ac1    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-123456789012          10        2020-02-10 09:00:00
398fdd112    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-123456789012         647        2020-02-11 09:00:00
561e4c033    1beced7e-b0ad-43e7-bd8d-d3c7cf2a1234          99        2020-02-12 10:00:00
63a997ac4    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-xxxxxa3b0396          10        2020-02-13 09:00:00
398fdd115    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-xxxxxa3b0396         777        2020-02-14 09:00:00
561e4c036    1beced7e-b0ad-43e7-bd8d-d3c7cf2axxxx         234        2020-02-15 10:00:00
63a997ac7    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-906d2a3baaaa         610        2020-02-16 09:00:00
398fdd118    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-906d2a3baaaa         647        2020-02-17 09:00:00
561e4c039    1beced7e-b0ad-43e7-bd8d-d3c7cf2axxxx         999        2020-02-18 10:00:00
```

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
    { $match:
        {ucode: {$in:[:listOfUcode]},
        createDate: {
            "$gte": ISODate(:start),
            "$lte": ISODate(:end)
                }              
        }
    },
    { $sort: { ucode: 1, createDate: -1 } },
])
```

This is the result I would like to get.

```
_id                        ucode                         value           createDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
398fdd112    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-123456789012         647        2020-02-11 09:00:00
561e4c033    1beced7e-b0ad-43e7-bd8d-d3c7cf2a1234          99        2020-02-12 10:00:00
398fdd115    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-xxxxxa3b0396         777        2020-02-14 09:00:00
398fdd118    08905ba5-4188-4f5f-b982-906d2a3baaaa         647        2020-02-17 09:00:00
561e4c039    1beced7e-b0ad-43e7-bd8d-d3c7cf2axxxx         999        2020-02-18 10:00:00
```

Someone could help me with the adjustment in the query?

**.:SOLUTION:.**

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
    { $match:
        {ucode: {$in:[:listOfUcode]},
        createDate: {
            "$gte": ISODate(:start),
            "$lte": ISODate(:end)
                }              
        }
    },
    { $sort: { ucode: 1, createDate: -1 } },
    { $group:{
        _id: "$ucode",
        lastDateTransaction:{$first: "$createDate"},
        numberOfTransactionsInThePeriod: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: You'll want to `$group` them (probably using `$first` with `$$ROOT`)

Comment: PERFECT!!!! thnks @user20042973